# Vue3 + TS PropType of a generic

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to have a prop as a generic type.

at the moment I have something like this.

```
props: {
    items: {
      type: Array as PropType<string[] | unknown[]>,
      required: true,
    },
}
```

and im looking for using a generic type `T` as a prop:

```
    items: {
      type: Array as PropType<string[] | T[]>,
      required: true,
    },
```

is there a way I can achieve that? thanks for coming by!

Comment: What is the purpose of this generic? Where do you expect to provide T type?

Comment: @EstusFlask later i use a scoped slot which call a function iterating in every item in the array D:

Comment: Then you likely can cast a type with `as` inside a function and make `unknown` more specific but I don't see how a generic could be applicable on component level.